# Bound on the absolute difference

Tags: real-numbers

Let $A$, $\overline{A}$, $\underline{A}$ and $B$ be real numbers, and let $\underline{A}\le A\le \overline{A}$. Is the following correct?
$$
|A-B| = \max\{A-B, B-A\} \le \max\{\overline{A}-B, B-\underline{A}\} 
$$

Apologies for the elementary question.

Comment: Well, $$\underline A\leqslant A\implies -\underline A\geqslant-A\implies B-\underline A\geqslant B-A\\\overline A\geqslant A\implies \overline A-B\geqslant A-B$$

Comment: Thanks @G.Sassatelli So you're saying that I am correct, right?

Comment: Yes: the last inequality comes from the fact that each number in the first $\max\{\ \}$ is smaller that some number in the second $\max\{\ \}$